# Adwords add history for domain

Tags: google-ads-api

I am working on Google Adwords api, I need to make software, ads which are created for specific domain I should be able to track the history of that. To be more specific here is the url which does 100% same like i wanted to make. 
http://www.semrush.com/info/halfpricebanners.com+(by+adwords_historical)

I searched in the Google adwords they only provide your own account history so how we can get the history who are not registered with me.

Other thing is finding specific key word domain competitor for more specific what i want to make is something like that 
http://www.semrush.com/info/halfpricebanners.com+(by+adwords_adwords)

Which tool of adword provide this kind of data? can any one help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

> I searched in the Google adwords they only provide your own account history so how we can get the history who are not registered with me.

Quite simply - you can't.

The first thing to say is that the SEMRush data you linked to is not provided by the AdWords API.

I suspect that they have a system that automates searches and scrapes the SERP for details of interest.

It's also worth noting that the data they provide isn't 100% accurate.

The only data AdWords provides along a similar nature is auction insights reports:

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2579754?hl=en-GB

But these are only available for terms you are already advertising on and also not currently available through the api (Although there is a live thread on the AdWords API forum suggesting they are possibly looking into doing so)

Comment: Thank you for response. I just studied again and again the competitor url. How they are getting still not understanding. Because we can get competitor keyword if we have already domain. But based on domain how they will get competitor domain do i am missing something.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what it is you are asking.